# Linear change of variables and Integration domain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have to deal with the following 4D integral

$$\int_{0}^{\Delta T} d t_{1} \int_{0}^{\Delta T} d t_{2} \int_{0}^{t_{1}} d \tau_{1} \int_{0}^{t_{2}} d \tau_{2} \, f(t_{1} - \tau_{1}) \, f(t_{2} - \tau_{2}) \, g (\tau_{1} - \tau_{2}) $$

In order to estimate it, it seems legitimate to consider the following change of variables

$$\begin{cases} 
u_{1} = t_{1} - \tau_{1}
\\
u_{2} = t_{2} - \tau_{2}
\\
v_{1} = \tau_{1} + \tau_{2}
\\
v_{2} = \tau_{1} - \tau_{2}
\end{cases}$$

The determinant of this linear transformation is $2$, so that the integral becomes

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{D} du_{1} \, du_{2} \, dv_{1} \, dv_{2} \, f(u_{1}) \, f(u_{2}) \, g(v_{2})$$

However, I am not able to determine the appropriate integration boundaries in order to explicitly perform this integration.

For the moment, I have only been able to get to the following point

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\Delta T} d u_{1} \int_{0}^{\Delta T} d u_{2} \int_{?}^{?} d v_{2} \int_{?}^{?} d v_{1} \, f(u_{1}) \, f(u_{2}) \, g(v_{2}) $$

For such linear change of variables, I usually really on a geometrical interpretation, but here, in 4D, it is not straightforwardly possible...

How could I proceed to easily find these missing bounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had the courage to look carefully of the bounds of integration. It may be useful for someone, so the final answer is

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\Delta T} d u_{1} \int_{0}^{\Delta t} d u_{2} \int_{- (\Delta T - u_{2})}^{\Delta T - u_{1}} d v_{2} \int_{|v_{2}|}^{2 \Delta T - u_{1} - u_{2} - |v_{2} + u_{1} - u_{2}|} d v_{1} \, f (u_{1}) \, f(u_{2}) \, g (v_{2}) $$